# How to read a key from the keyboard in c# winforms Form3 panel1_Paint button10()

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop

I have a panel1_Paint used to Paint a display in panel2_Paint.
I am reading the keyboard from form_KeyPress like this.

```
    private void form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        scankeyinput3 += e.KeyChar.ToString();

        if (scankeyinput3 != "") { scankeyinput4 = ""; }

        if (keyboardInputLength2 >= 1)
        {
            scankeyinput4 = scankeyinput3.Substring(scankeyinput3.Length - 1);
        }
        scankeyinput3 = scankeyinput4;

        ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keydata);
    }
```

I am using ProcessCmdKey to get the keyboard key in Form3.

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {
        scankeyinput6 = keyData.ToString();
        Form3.textchangedtextbox2 = 4;

        if (scankeyinput6 == "None") { scankeyinput6 = "@"; }
        if (scankeyinput6 == "Next") { scankeyinput6 = "@"; }

        if (scankeyinput6 == "@") { Form3.textchangedtextbox2 = 0; }
        if (scankeyinput6 == "#") { Form3.textchangedtextbox2 = 0; }

        if (scankeyinput6 != "") { scankeyinput4 = ""; }
        keyboardInputLength2 = scankeyinput6.Length;

        if (keyboardInputLength2 >= 1)
        {
            scankeyinput4 = scankeyinput6.Substring(scankeyinput6.Length - 1);
        }
        scankeyinput6 = scankeyinput4;

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

The problem I am having is to get the keyboard key when I am in Form3 panel1_Paint button10().
I can not get focus on Form3 panel1_Paint button10().
Hence I can not get a key read from,
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)

I would like to know how to get focus on the button10().
I get the keyboard read to return a key in form, Form1, Form2, and From3 with the code here.
I can not get focus on button10().

I tried getting the key using textboxes which was not fuctional.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you want to receive a "hot key" type message regardless of which form or control is focused. You can achieve this objective by implementing [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter) for your main form.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }

    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg.Equals(WM_KEYDOWN))
        {
            Keys key = (Keys)m.WParam | ModifierKeys;
            ProcessKeyboardHookKey(new KeyEventArgs(key));
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void ProcessKeyboardHookKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string scankeyinput6 = e.KeyData.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(scankeyinput6);

    #if false
        // D O    S O M E T H I N G

        Form3.textchangedtextbox2 = 4;

        if (scankeyinput6 == "None") { scankeyinput6 = "@"; }
        if (scankeyinput6 == "Next") { scankeyinput6 = "@"; }

        if (scankeyinput6 == "@") { Form3.textchangedtextbox2 = 0; }
        if (scankeyinput6 == "#") { Form3.textchangedtextbox2 = 0; }

        if (scankeyinput6 != "") { scankeyinput4 = ""; }
        keyboardInputLength2 = scankeyinput6.Length;

        if (keyboardInputLength2 >= 1)
        {
            scankeyinput4 = scankeyinput6.Substring(scankeyinput6.Length - 1);
        }
        scankeyinput6 = scankeyinput4;
    #endif
    }
}
```